# Remainder in taylor's theorem for multivariate functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Excerpt is from Courant Intro Analysis book Vol 2 pg 69.  I need explanation of the underlined part (entire sentence) including justification.  I understand what vanishes to higher order means.

[image]

Comment: what is the name of that book?

Comment: @JimmySabater Hi i edited to include book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the meaning of the Landau symbol, "little oh".  That is, $f(x)= o(g(x))$ means $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.  I.e. $f$ goes to zero "at higher order" than $g$.

For instance,  $x^n=o(x^m)$ for $n\gt m$.

Thus the result you have underlined follows from the fact that the remainder $R_n$ has higher powers of $h$ and $k$ than  $d^nf$ does.  This information is on the page above.

Comment: How do you prove that the ratio of the two polynomials in $h$ and $k$ go to $0$?  Is there are Hopital rule for multivariable functions?
Also I still don't see the relevance of the very last part that $R_n=o(\sqrt{(h^2+k^2)^n})$

Comment: For the last part, try squaring both sides.  One is a polynomial of degree  $2n$, the other $2n+2$.  Polynomials of higher degree grow (and decay) faster, a basic fact.

Comment: What's a rough proof sketch of "Polynomials of higher degree grow (and decay) faster"?

Comment: The highest degree term dominates.

Comment: Factor it out;  then compare terms of highest degree.

Comment: factor what out..?  If you have a clear proof of this can you just type it full please.

Comment: $a_nx^n+\dots+a_0=x^n(a_n+a_{n-1}x^{-1}+\dots+a_0x^{-n})$.  Every term in parentheses approaches $0$, except $a_n$.  This fact reduces it to comparing.   $x^n$ and $x^m$.  Which is easy.

Comment: Every term in parentheses approaches $0$?  Every term approaches infinity as $x$ goes to infinity...

Comment: No, $x^{-m}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Oops I meant $x$ goes to 0.  That is what we are considering.  That a polynomial of higher degree, decays faster as its variables approach $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89145/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-helios321).